# How to filter out lines within each row in R?

Tags: r, filter, text-mining, preprocessor

I have been trying since many days on this problem but couldn't get the expected results.

I have a dataframe containing conversations of two person A & B within each row (it is like 1 row contains entire conversation, likewise i have thousand of rows). i want to filter out lines in each row based on certain keywords.

How can i do that?

I have tried below lines but couldn't get exact results.

```
March_Data_fil <- March_Data %>% filter(!str_detect(March_Data, 'Have a good|Thank|day|Ty|thanx|Cheers|How r u|'))

    > head(my_data)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Transcript
    1 00:00:34 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:00:35 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:00:35 Bot: \n00:00:45 You: No work\n00:00:48 Bot: Please select your type of work\n00:00:48 Bot: null\n00:00:53 Bot: Please select your location\n00:00:54 Bot: null\n00:01:00 Bot: Thank you, let me connect you with someone to help with this. I'll also pass on the history of our chat.\n00:01:00 Bot: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number\n00:18:11 xyz: ill get back to you shortly\n00:18:15 info: Thank you for chatting with us.\n
    2                                           00:05:57 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:05:58 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:05:58 Bot: \n00:06:17 You: I have no work.\n00:06:19 Bot: Please select your type of work\n00:06:20 Bot: null\n00:06:24 You: I&M\n00:06:25 Bot: Please select your location\n00:06:25 Bot: null\n00:06:28 Bot: Thank you, let me connect you with someone to help with this. I'll also pass on the history of our chat.\n00:06:29 Bot: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number\n00:07:49 ***: Thanks\n
    3                                           00:05:57 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:05:58 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:05:58 Bot: \n00:06:17 You: I have no work.\n00:06:19 Bot: Please select your type of work\n00:06:20 Bot: null\n00:06:24 You: I&M\n00:06:25 Bot: Please select your location\n00:06:25 Bot: null\n00:06:28 Bot: Thank you, let me connect you with someone to help with this. I'll also pass on the history of our chat.\n00:06:29 Bot: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number\n00:07:49 ***: Thanks\n
    4 00:00:34 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:00:35 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:00:35 Bot: \n00:00:45 You: No work\n00:00:48 Bot: Please select your type of work\n00:00:48 Bot: null\n00:00:53 Bot: Please select your location\n00:00:54 Bot: null\n00:01:00 Bot: Thank you, let me connect you with someone to help with this. I'll also pass on the history of our chat.\n00:01:00 Bot: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number\n00:18:11 xyz: ill get back to you shortly\n00:18:15 info: Thank you for chatting with us.\n
    5                                           00:05:57 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:05:58 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:05:58 Bot: \n00:06:17 You: I have no work.\n00:06:19 Bot: Please select your type of work\n00:06:20 Bot: null\n00:06:24 You: I&M\n00:06:25 Bot: Please select your location\n00:06:25 Bot: null\n00:06:28 Bot: Thank you, let me connect you with someone to help with this. I'll also pass on the history of our chat.\n00:06:29 Bot: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number\n00:07:49 ***: Thanks\n
       ID
    1 231
    2 243
    3 222
    4 123
    5 234
> str(my_data)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Transcript: chr  "00:00:34 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:00:35 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:"| __truncated__ "00:05:57 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:05:58 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:"| __truncated__ "00:05:57 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:05:58 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:"| __truncated__ "00:00:34 info: You’re now chatting with Bot Virtual Assistant\n00:00:35 Bot: What can I assist with today?\n00:"| __truncated__ ...
 $ ID        : int  231 243 222 123 234
```

can somebody please help me, i'm stuck on this since a week :(

Thanks,
Naseer

Comment: What are the results you're getting with this? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and update your question.

Comment: Question updated accordingly.

Comment: can you update with `head(March_Data)` so we can see the full structure?

Comment: Hi Peter, Updated the question with head.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split the strings by new line characters, remove the matching parts and re-combine the results to strings (assuming your data is in a character vector `x`):

```
remove_pattern = 'Have a good|Thank|day|Ty|thanx|Cheers|How r u'
res = lapply(strsplit(x, "\n", fixed = TRUE), function(x) {
  paste(grep(remove_pattern, x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE), collapse= "\n")
})

invisible(lapply(res, cat))
# 00:00:34 Botmessage: You’re now chatting with Botmessage Virtual Assistant
# 00:00:35 Botmessage: 
# 00:00:45 You: No work
# 00:00:48 Botmessage: Please select your type of work
# 00:00:48 Botmessage: null
# 00:00:51 You: I&M
# 00:01:24 Botmessage: 
# 00:01:25 Botmessage: Please wait while your chat is transferred to the appropriate group.00:05:18 Botmessage: You’re now chatting with Botmessage Virtual Assistant
# 00:05:20 Botmessage: 
# 00:08:07 You: No work
# 00:08:08 Botmessage: Please select your type of work
# 00:08:08 Botmessage: null
# 00:08:12 You: I&M
# 00:08:14 Botmessage: Please select your location
# 00:08:21 Botmessage: So I can transfer you, please provide me your ID number
# 00:08:33 Botmessage: 
# 00:08:33 Botmessage: Please wait while your chat is transferred to the appropriate group.
```

Comment: Hi Docendo, The code is throwing empty list when applied on column of data frame.
I have updated the question with head() & str(). Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this answer assumed a different desired output.

Try passing the variable that contains the strings instead of the entire `March_Data` dataframe to `str_detect`. Also, I don't know `str_detect`, but this would work assuming `March_Data` is a dataframe

```
March_Data_fil <- March_Data %>% dplyr::filter(
  !grepl('Have a good|Thank|day|Ty|thanx|Cheers|How r u|', variable_containing_strings))
```

Reproducible example:

```
dplyr::filter(iris, !grepl('setosa|virginica', Species))
```

Comment: Hi Pete, With your code, it is completely removing all rows. I want to remove lines within each row. I hope you got my point. Each row contains around 30-50 lines of conversation.